# C++ addition overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, stdstring

I am coming up against a vexing conundrum in my code base.  I can't quite tell why my code generates this error, but (for example) std::string does not.

```
class String {
public:
    String(const char*str);
    friend String operator+ ( const String& lval, const char *rval );
    friend String operator+ ( const char *lval, const String& rval );
    String operator+ ( const String& rval );
};
```

The implementation of these is easy enough to imagine on your own.

My driver program contains the following:

```
String result, lval("left side "), rval("of string");
char lv[] = "right side ", rv[] = "of string";
result = lv + rval;
printf(result);
result = (lval + rv);
printf(result);
```

Which generates the following error in gcc 4.1.2:

```
driver.cpp:25: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
String.h:22: note: candidate 1: String operator+(const String&, const char*)
String.h:24: note: candidate 2: String String::operator+(const String&)
```

So far so good, right? Sadly, my String(const char *str) constructor is so handy to have as an implicit constructor, that using the explicit keyword to solve this would just cause a different pile of problems.

Moreover... std::string doesn't have to resort to this, and I can't figure out why.  For example, in basic_string.h,  they are declared as follows:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
          const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __rhs)

template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs,
          const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>& __rhs);
```

and so on.  The basic_string constructor is not declared explicit.  How does this not cause the same error I'm getting, and how can I achieve the same behavior??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the ambiguity is that one candidate function is better than another candidate function only if *none* of its parameters are a worse match than the parameters of the other.  Consider your two functions:

```
friend String operator+(const String&, const char*); // (a)
String operator+(const String&);                     // (b)
```

You are calling `operator+` with a `String` and a `const char*`.

The second argument, of type `const char*`, clearly matches (a) better than (b).  It is an exact match for (a), but a user-defined conversion is required for (b).

Therefore, in order for there to be an ambiguity, the first argument must match (b) better than (a).

The `String` on the left-hand side of the call to `operator+` is not const.  Therefore, it matches (b), which is a non-const member function, better than (a), which takes a `const String&`.

Therefore, any of the following solutions would remove the ambiguity:

- Change the member `operator+` to be a const member function
- Change the non-member `operator+` to take a `String&` instead of a `const String&`
- Call `operator+` with a const String on the left hand side

Obviously, the first, [also suggested by UncleBens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613645/c-addition-overload-ambiguity/2613836#2613836), is the best way to go.

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind that the const-ness would be cause for a bad match.  You and UncleBens were (of course) exactly right.  One more solution would actually be to make the member a non-member that accepts two const Strings - this is actually why the std::string version has no error.  Of course, this is equivalent to your first suggestion, just written differently.

Answer (score 5):

It is sufficient in this case just to define on `operator+`:

```
String operator+(const String& lval, const String& rval);
```

Because you provide a constructor taking a `char*`, a `String` can be constructed from a `char*` during the call to `operator+`.  For example:

```
String hello = "Hello, ";
const char* world = "world!";

String helloWorld = hello + world;
```

A temporary `String` will be constructed with the contents of the `char*` `world` (because your constructor is not explicit), then the two `String` objects will be passed to `operator+`.

Comment: That creates a useless temporary object, possibly at considerable cost in time and memory.

Comment: @Daniel Newby: Not really, as the compiler is able to elude the copy quite often. Also that "considerable cost of time and memory" is exactly what `std::string` does, as asked by the OP in his original post.

Answer (score 3):

The error goes away if you declare the member + **const** as it should be.

```
class String {
public:
    String(const char*str);
    friend String operator+ ( const String& lval, const char *rval );
    friend String operator+ ( const char *lval, const String& rval );
    String operator+ ( const String& rval ) const; //<-- here
};
```

<s>Not sure what's the reason, though. Perhaps it prefers binding arguments to const reference if possible, so the first overload is a better match for the left-hand value and the third overload has a better match for the right-hand value.</s>

[Better explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613645/c-addition-overload-ambiguity/2614085#2614085) (Must have misread the problem a bit.)

---

```
printf(result);
```

Don't tell me your String has implicit conversion to `const char*`... That's evil.

Comment: Hopefully that's a non-standard printf function found through ADL.  Although it should be `puts`, not `printf`, if all it does is print the argument.

Comment: `puts` adds a new-line, though. I suppose it should be `printf("%s", str.c_str());` if the newline is not wanted.

Comment: +1 This is arguably the best option.  I've tried to explain the ambiguity:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613645/c-addition-overload-ambiguity/2614085#2614085

Comment: Though I know why you're saying that, I think that evil is in the eyes of the beholder ;)

Answer (score 2):

Template and non-template functions follow different rules. The template functions are selected on the actual parameter types, without any conversions being applied. In the case of the non-template (i.e. your code) an implicit conversion can be applied. Thus the templated stuff in basic_string is not ambiguous, but yours is.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that `basic_string` has implementations of `operator+` corresponding to the second and third operators in your class `String`. Does `basic_string` also have an operator corresponding to your first operator [`friend String operator+ ( const String& lval, const char *rval );`]?

What happens if you remove this operator?